# Best approach to package Windows Universal Application with a Winforms Application

Tags: winforms, win-universal-app

I have a bit of a predicament in which I am seeking some advice and I currently have limited knowledge with regards to whole Universal applications.

I currently have a Winforms application that needs to call the CameraCaptureUI control; however, it turns out that this control is native to Windows 8.1 and Universal applications.

At first I was going to convert the application to a Universal; however, this isn't a possibility since it relies on some third party software that isn't available as portable library targetting the .Net Core fraemwork, and is unable to be converted to one at the time.

I thought I might go with a portable library, but this was a deal breaker b/c I couldn't reference the CameraCaptureUI control.

My next logical step was that since this class is unavailable via a regular Winforms project, I thought I could add a Universal project to the solution and use it as a wrapper to call the CameraCaptureUI.  I could then perform the processing I needed from within the other executable by seting up a ProcessStartInfo pointing to the executable of the Universal application and wait for it to complete.  This would be fine; however, you cannot run a Universal application without the context of an app container.

That brings me to my current predicament.  What would you recommend as the best approach to tackling this?  I really need to call the executable from the Universal app, or at the very least the CameraCaptureUI, from within the Winforms application.  Calling the Camera straight up isn't an option because I need to be able to retrieve the photo(s)/video(s) the user took.  I'd also like to keep it to a single installation instance.  We do currently use ClickOnce as our deployment method.

Has anyone else ran across this before or could offer some suggestions?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: It is technically possible to use a WinRT class from a Winforms app.  You'll have to do [pretty unpleasant things](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications) to your project and you'll have a pretty hard time to make it work on any machine  Which in general makes it a bad idea, it was quite possible to use a camera in code before 2012.  Really.  What you need to know to use it the olden way is impossible to guess.

Comment: Funny that you mention this, I'm actually using it for the GPS. However, it appears even using this you can't call the CameraCaptureUI from the Winforms app, unless I was missing something.